# ASP.net MVC wkhtmltopdf system process font issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, fonts, webserver, wkhtmltopdf

I'm using the wkhtmltopdf application to convert my ASP.net MVC 2 rendered HTML into a PDF and display the PDF instead of the standard view for better print ability. Everything works great minus one thing. When I run wkhtmltopdf as a process in my MVC application on our webserver it does not display the installed barcode font in the PDF.

Here is the code for the process.

```
public void HtmlToPdf(string url, string appPath)
    {

        string message = null;
        // to build command argument
        StringBuilder argument = new StringBuilder();
        // input html file
        string switches = "";
        switches += "--print-media-type ";
        switches += "--margin-top 10mm --margin-bottom 10mm --margin-right 10mm --margin-left 10mm ";
        switches += "--page-size Letter ";
        switches += "--load-error-handling ignore ";
        switches += "--username admin ";
        switches += "--password pass ";
        argument.Append(switches + " " + url + " " + "C:\\PDF\\temp.pdf");


        // to call the exe to convert

        System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
        p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        p.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\wkhtmltopdf\\wkhtmltopdf.exe";
        p.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\wkhtmltopdf";
        p.StartInfo.Arguments = argument.ToString();

        p.Start();
        p.WaitForExit();
        message = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(message))
        {
            message = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        }
        else
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(message);
        }
    }
```

Not really sure why it wont show the barcode because it shows in the when you render the html but not in when the wkhtmltopddf converts it to pdf. It also works correctly if you run wkhtmltopdf out side of my MVC application.

-Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it in a while with an updated version of wkhtmltopdf?

Which version was this a problem with? I recently tried to generate using a random font I downloaded and it worked fine.

If you generate the PDF on a server the server needs the font too, I assume you know that but someone else reading might not realize it :)
Could I get the font in question to test on my system? 
Was the conversion done in what environment? (Most likely not Linux due to asp.net, but asking just in case)